# iOS Calling Twitter API 1.1 with OAuth

Tags: ios, twitter, oauth

I want upload my profile image and other images to twitter in iOS app . I am trying to integrate Twitter . I got the Oauth token and token_secret from dev.twitter.com. I have add the those detail with my request but i receive "Bad authentication". I googled to get sample to send OAuth detail with Twitter REST API but i couldn't find any suitable example. Please give me any sample code to send OAuth with Twitter REST API.

Here is my code

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?user_id=%@",accont.identifier];

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest
                                    requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request addValue:OAUTH_TOKEN forHTTPHeaderField:@"oauth_token"];

[request addValue:OAUTH_TOKEN_SECCRET forHTTPHeaderField:@"oauth_token_secret"];

NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine) this is latest and very well managed library. where you can get all tweets, followers, all info

To get Profile Picture from Twitter you can use following code in FHSTwitterEngine

```
[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]permanentlySetConsumerKey:@"<consumer_key>" andSecret:@"<consumer_secret>"];
[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]showOAuthLoginControllerFromViewController:self
withCompletion:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
        UIImage *profileImg = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine] getProfileImageForUsername:@"<username>" andSize:size];
    }
}];
```

Comment: thanks @the1pawan. I'm not trying to upload, i want to download images from twitter into my app

Comment: @iOSDeveloper you can see my Edit.. let me know if u have any pther query